# what else can i use instead of htp.print and dbms_output on toad for oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: html, plsql, toad

At the moment i have htp.print and DBMS_output to show the me the end result of user input. however, htp.print shows the confirmed message on the web browser and my DBMS_output doesn't work for some reason. But what i'm looking for is the confirmation message which will pop up and show to the user. i have tried java script and for some reason that is not working either. below are the syntax.

-- button and input text field

```
HTP.FORMOPEN ('BANINST1.UAP.P_UNSUSPEND_SEARCH', 'post');
    HTP.P ('<input type="text" method="post" name="bannerid" id="bannerid" placeholder="e.g. 000123456" maxlength="9" 
            autocomplete="off" required>');
 HTP.FORMSUBMIT ('', 'Submit', cattributes => 'onclick="confirmMsg()"');
    HTP.FORMCLOSE;
```

-- javascript confirmation message which is not working

```
htp.p ('<script type="text/javascript">
                        function confirmMsg() {
                                var field1 = document.getElementById("bannerid").value;
                                alert(field1+" has been unsuspended");
                                }   
                   </script>');
```

Comment: have you tried running in a browser like chrome and using the F12 console to see if you are getting JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for ways to generate log messages from the DB Backend, I see basically 2 ways to achieve this:

(1) Persist your messages to a table inside an autonomous transaction. A complete example can be found [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_autonomous_transaction.htm).

(2) If you have access to the DB servers file system, you can also write messages to text files using the [UTIL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-EBC42A36-EB72-4AA1-B75F-8CF4BC6E29B4) package.